# Binding on XAML Popup's Opened Event

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I need to run some logic every time a Popup element is shown (due to dynamic size of its contents and, in my case, the position of the popup).

The following XAML and handler do not work, although they are ripped directly from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.opened(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Popup x:Name="Foo" Opened="Foo_Opened">
  ...
</Popup>

void Foo_Opened(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  ...
}
```

This fails to build with the message:

```
No overload for 'Foo_Opened' matches delegate System.EventHandler<object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual method signature accepted here is:

```
void Foo_Opened(object sender, object args)
{
  ...
}
```